# how to test componentWillUnmount

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have following code in a class component and I am trying to test the componentWillUnmount.

```
export class Hello extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.isCLoseFromHeaderClicked = true;
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    if(this.isCLoseFromHeaderClicked) { this.props.closeModal(); }
  }
 ....do some other stuff...
}
```

I wrote test case for it as follows

```
  describe('componentWillUnmount', () => {
    it('componentWillUnmount should be called', () => {
        wrapper = shallowWithIntl(<Hello {...props} />);
        const componentWillUnmount = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'componentWillUnmount');
        wrapper.unmount();
        expect(componentWillUnmount).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```

This test case passes but coverage is not meeting. I also need to test the else part

[image]

Does anyone know how can i test the else part?

Comment: but you don't have ```else``` part. You should rather test that closeModal is called when ```isCloseFromHeaderClicked``` is true. (test 1). And test 2, that it is __not__ called when ```isCloseFromHeaderClicked``` is false

Comment: Thanks @grodzi Yes you are right but I couldnt find example of that. Can you give me an example how to set values values for isCloseFromHeaderClicked?

Comment: I have no env to test (nor the courage). I would simply try ```wrapper.instance().isCloseFrom... = false``` (before unmounting)

Comment: Thank you so much @grodzi. That did it. If you just add that same comment then i'll mark it an answer :)

Comment: glad to have been of help @User7354632781 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply try `wrapper.instance().isCloseFrom... = false` (before unmounting) in order to test that `closeModal` is not called